# JavaScript won't parse a YouTube URL

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to make a script that will parse a YouTube URL using RegExp on JavaScript to get the video ID, like this:

```
function youtube_id_extract(url) {
  var youtube_id;
  youtube_id = url.replace(/^[^v]+v.(.{11}).*/,"$1");

  return youtube_id;
}
```

But I've tried with this URL: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hb_IXwcwcjg and it won't parse.  What is wrong with this RegEx?

Comment: It works...http://jsfiddle.net/WnRzs/

Answer (score 4):

It works fine:

```
> var url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hb_IXwcwcjg";
> var youtube_id = url.replace(/^[^v]+v.(.{11}).*/,"$1");
"Hb_IXwcwcjg"
```

However your regular expression is more complicated then it needs to be. You could try this instead which has the same effect (except that it fails with an error if the string doesn't match, instead of silently returning the same string):

```
youtube_id = url.match(/\?v=(.*)/)[1];
```

Comment: I'm using this on a if function, that I got from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855666/4855691#4855691

Comment: In the second example it won't work when I try using the ID, neither the URL. I got this: `[null] is not an object.`

Comment: @Brian: I guess your string isn't what you think it is, or else you haven't copy+pasted correctly. Try opening a Javascript console and pasting the code from your question - you will see that it runs fine.

Comment: @Brian: You haven't posted the code full for `youtube_do`. The error is most likely in some of the code you haven't posted.

Comment: @Mark: The code is exactly the same as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855666/4855691#4855691

Answer (score 1):

This is from the official google/youtube docs:

```
getId : function(url) {
    return /https?:\/\/(?:[a-zA_Z]{2,3}.)?(?:youtube\.com\/watch\?)((?:[\w\d\-\_\=]+&amp;(?:amp;)?)*v(?:&lt;[A-Z]+&gt;)?=([0-9a-zA-Z\-\_]+))/i.exec(url)[2];
}
```